# Why can't I get the value of this var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I want to create a live change field input system with jQuery. This is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').on('dblclick', function() {
    var tdValue = $(this).text();
    var tdTag = $(this).html();

    tdTag = '<input id="newClass" type="text" value="' + tdValue + '">';

    $(this).html(tdTag);
    
    $('input#newClass').on('change', function() {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      alert('inputVal =  ' + inputVal);

      var inputTag = $(this).html();
      alert('inputTag = ' + inputTag);

      var var3 = '<span> var3 ' + inputTag + '</span>';
      alert(var3);
    })
  })
})
```

Why is `inputTag` and `var3` empty? This is my (very simple) html code

[image: MY LITTLE HTML CODE]

Note that the `td` tags are repeated using a PHP `while` loop. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your javascript is looking for an `<input>` with class `newClass`, but in your html it's an `id`. (And you shouldn't use the same ID for more than one element, if there are multiple.)

Comment: What is the expected value of `inputTag` and `var3`? `html()` gets contents of the element, and since `input` is an empty element, of course that you get an empty string.

Comment: Thanks Robin in fact I've already done that but same problem 
the problem is when to get the html code at the variable inputTag

Comment: @nik0la.vr I was expecting to get something similar to that (after on.('change' )
<td> <input id = "newClass" type = "text" value = "Hors ligne bla bla "> </ td>

Comment: @Robin in addition it's not the iD that repeats but just td ..in addition ... a single td will have an identifier

Comment: So you would like to get an actual HTML code of the element: `inputTag = <td><input id = "newClass" type = "text" value = "Hors ligne bla bla"></td>`?

Comment: @nik0la.vr  Yes ..true .. i want to re transform input to span .. and to be not changeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I don't have enough reputation to comment and I'm still confused. Try following codes and see if anything suits you.

```
var inputTag = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
```

or

```
var inputTag = $(this).parent()[0].outerHTML;
```

or

```
var var3 = '<span>' + inputVal + '</span>';
$(this).after(var3);
$(this).remove();
```

or if you just want to make the input field read only, try with

```
$(this).prop("readonly", true);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! yes it works like a charm :) .. I have chosen third part of your code ...  I will continue on the line of jQuery ..  Have a nice day